# How to update MUI X data grid table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

I am using MUI X Data grid and performing an action on row, say delete.
I could able to delete data in back end, but after delete how could I update state to latest data?

```
  const handleConfirmDelete = (expenseId) => {
    setOpenConfirmDelete(true);
    setfetchExpenseId(expenseId)
  };

  const handleDeleteCompleted = async () => {

    // Function for delete

    await deleteExpense(fetchExpenseId)

    // How can I refresh datagrid here?

    setOpenConfirmDelete(false);
    
    console.log(fetchExpenseId)
    enqueueSnackbar(t('The user account has been removed'), {
      variant: 'success',
      anchorOrigin: {
        vertical: 'top',
        horizontal: 'right'
      },
      TransitionComponent: Zoom
    });
  };
```

Below is columns created for deletefunction

```
  const columns = [
    { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 90 },
    {
      field: "expense_date",
      headerName: "Expense Date",
      width: 150,
      editable: true,
      flex: 2,
    },
    {
      field: "actions",
      headerName: "Actions",
      editable: true,
      flex: 1,
      renderCell: (params) => (
        <Typography noWrap>
          <Tooltip title={t("View")} arrow>
            <IconButton onClick={() => handleViewExpense(params.id)} color="primary">
              <LaunchTwoToneIcon fontSize="small" />
            </IconButton>
          </Tooltip>
          <IconButton onClick={() => handleConfirmDelete(params.id)} color="primary">
            <DeleteTwoToneIcon fontSize="small" />
          </IconButton>
        </Typography>
      ),
    },
  ];
```

Here is the data grid table

```
       <div style={{ height: 800, width: "100%" }}>
            <DataGrid
              rows={expenses}
              columns={columns}
              pageSize={5}
              rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
              checkboxSelection
              disableSelectionOnClick
              components={{
                Toolbar: GridToolbar,
              }}
              columnVisibilityModel={columnVisibilityModel}
              pageSize={pageSize}
              onPageSizeChange={(newPageSize) => setPageSize(newPageSize)}
              rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 20]}
              pagination
              autoHeight
            />
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your code and variable **expenses** snippet is inside

```
useEffect(() => {...})[]
```